# How to do svn up --accept mine-full in Subclipse (eclipse plugin)

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I need to overwrite remote svn repo with local content.
The only tool in the environment I got is Eclipse with Subclipse.

The question is: How can I do `svn up --accept mine-full` in Subclipse.

Simply trying to commit results with tons of conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do Team > Update and when you are prompted for conflicts you choose the accept option and check the box to apply the same to all.  Note there is an Update to Revision option that brings up a dialog where you can pre-set these options.

But note that update will not do anything to fix conflicts you already have in your working copy.  It will just control what happens when you do the update for any new conflicts coming in.

If you have files with local conflicts, you can take the Team > Resolve option and choose one of these actions as well.

UPDATE: I did miss one thing.  If you take the normal Update to HEAD option it will simply create conflicts and not prompt you to resolve.  You can do it after using Team > Resolve option.  However, in the preferences you can change the defaults.  Go to Team > SVN > Update to HEAD in the Eclipse preferences.  This will let you set it to Prompt you during update.